# tabulator adding element to columns and do action

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I have a very bad problem while working with Tabulator plugin.
I have a column which contains the title.Now I want to have another column to put 3 buttons inside it.

1. One `<a>` tag button to go to the link.
2. One button to edit;I want to show me a modal and call an ajax.
3. I already have a switch button plugin.I don't know how can I add it to this column and active it.

- I couldn't find my answer in Tabulator documents.

Comment: To be clear this grouping of buttons will be repeated for each row, correct?  If so why not three columns, each with it's own widget?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a custom formatter.

You start by defining the cell formatter function, which in this case will create the button elements *(you can add other functionality in here to customise the contents/look and feel of the buttons)*, add some event listeners to handle the buttons being clicked, then append them to the cell

```js
function buttonFormatter(cell){
    var cellEl = cell.getElement(); //get cell DOM element

    // create elements
    var linkBut document.createElement("button");
    var edtiBut document.createElement("button");
    var otherBut document.createElement("button");

    //add event bindings
    linkBut.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        //do something when link button clicked
    });

    //add buttons to cell
    cellEl.appendChild(linkBut);
    cellEl.appendChild(edtiBut);
    cellEl.appendChild(otherBut);
}
```

Then you bind the formatter function to the column using the ***formatter*** property in the column definition:

```js
   {title:"buttons", formatter:buttonFormatter),
```

Full details on using custom formatters can be found in the [Formatter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/format#format-custom)